# Array issue in MIPS using mars

Tags: arrays, mips

Here is my code and the error is in either reading or writing in the array. This has stumped me for quite awhile now, slowly getting better but not perfect.

One example output is the following:

please enter a number to test it's perfectness, or enter 0 to quit 
8

Factors are:

124665658

The sum is:

7

This value is

Please enter a number to test it's perfectness, or enter 0 to quit

```
.data     
isPerfect: .asciiz "\nThis Value is Perfect!\n"
isNotPerfect: .asciiz "\nThis value is not perfect :(\n"
negNum: .asciiz "\nPlease only enter positive values \n"
enterNum: .asciiz "\nPlease enter a number to test it's perfectness, or enter 0 to quit \n"
factors: .asciiz "\nFactors are: \n"
sum: .asciiz "\n The sum is: \n"
intVal: .word 0

.text

#DOCUMENTATION OF REGISTERS
#######################################################################################

#s0- user input
#s1- iterator
#s2 - iteration amount
#s3 - s0/2
#s4 - Remainder
#s5 - total
#Find the factors and store them in array add them up and compare them to $s0

#######################################################################################


#main
#prompts the user then goes to loop
#Also declares variables that should be reintialized upon a new user value
    .globl main
main:   move $s6, $zero
    la $t0, factorArray

    #variables declared prior to loops
    li $s2, 1
    li $s3, 1
    li $s5, 0

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, enterNum
    syscall

###########################################
#post main Values
# $s6 - 0
# $t0 - address of factorArray
# s2, s3, s5 look at code
###########################################

loop1:
    #retrieve input from user and store it in $s0
    li $v0, 5
    li $s1, 1
    syscall
    move $s0, $v0
    div $s3, $s0, 2

    li $s1, 0

    #Branch on greater than zero(Breaks down factors)
    bgtz $s0, factor
    #Brench on less than zero (Tells user they are bad and jumps back to loop)
    bltz $s0, negative
    #Branch on zero (End)
    b end

###########################################
#Post loop1 Values
#S1 - 1
#s0 - user input number
###########################################

factor:
    add $s1, $s1, $s2       #iterate
    rem $s4, $s0, $s1       #Get the remainder of the iterator and the user number



    beq $s4, $zero, storeValue  #if remainder is 0 store the value in the array
    ble $s1,$s3, factor     #branch if iterator is less than s0/2

    b print

###########################################
#post factor values
#$s4 is remainder of User inputer and iterator $s1
#$s3 Division User input, $s0 and 2 because no factors are < 2
###########################################


#shove factors in array
storeValue:


    add $s5, $s1, $s5

    sw $s1, 100($t0)
    addi $t0, $t0, 4
    addi $s6, $s6, 1
    b factor

###########################################
#post Storage values
#s5 is our total
#store iteration from $s1 in array
#incriment $t0 and %s6 both being address and place holder incrementations
###########################################

#to print the Array
print:
    la $t0, factorArray


    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, factors
    syscall

###########################################
#post print values
#$t0 - address of array
#drop our factors prompt
###########################################


for:    blt $s0, $s1, printSum
    li $v0, 1       
    lw $a0, 100($t0)        
    syscall 

    addi $t0, $t0, 4    
    addi $s6, $s6, 1
    addi $s1, $s1, 1
    b for

###########################################
#checks if $s0 and $s1 are equal
#Increments t0 and s6 and s1
###########################################

# Prints sum and decides if the number is perfect and branches accordingly #
printSum:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, sum
    syscall

    #print total here
    li $v0, 1
    sw $s5, intVal
    lw $a0, intVal
    syscall

    #perfect branch
    beq $s5, $s0, isPerfectImpl
    #not Perfect Branch
    b isNotPerfectImpl

###########################################
#post printSum values
#Loads contents of $t2 into inval
#needs re worked

###########################################

isPerfectImpl:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, isPerfect
    syscall
    b main

isNotPerfectImpl:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, isNotPerfect
    syscall
    b main

#Done
#Tels the user they are bad and jumps back to main to re prompt the user
negative:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, negNum
syscall
b main

end:    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

My output is the following and i am not really sure why

Comment: _"My output is the following"_ There's nothing following that sentence. Anyway, if you think something is wrong with your loads and stores, set breakpoints on the relevant functions and step through them.

Comment: what is the expected out put? or do you have description that explain what should this program do?